# Can't print some big values stored in a variable of type long long

Tags: c++, 64-bit, printf

I use Visual Studio 2010 x64 Process

```
int main()
{
  long long EntryPoint = 0x13f501000;
  printf("Value %x", EntryPoint);
  system("pause");
}
```

Result value is 3f501000 what not 13f501000?

Comment: Use more type-safe output methods, like std::cout

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`%llx` specifier with printf()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tcxf1dw6.aspx):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    const long long EntryPoint = 0x13f501000;
    printf("Value: 0x%llx", EntryPoint);
}
```

Basically, you can use the `ll` prefix (for `long long`) with the `x` type specifier.

**Command line:**

> ```
> C:\Temp\CppTests>cl /EHsc /W4 /nologo test.cpp
> test.cpp
>
> C:\Temp\CppTests>test.exe
> Value: 0x13f501000
> ```

---

In addition, since this question has the `[c++]` tag, you may consider using `std::cout` with **`std::hex`**:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    const long long EntryPoint = 0x13f501000;
    std::cout << "0x" << std::hex << EntryPoint << '\n';
}
```